# I need an explanation on [name] in this dictionary, more info on the post. (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am slightly confused about the [name] on the language variable on the second last line, next to the favourite_languages. I dont really understand why the code works with [name] there. Is it like the key which accesses the value of the current key that you are looping through? Thanks. (This is an exercise on the python crashcourse book and I dont really understand the explanation)

```
# for name in favourite_languages.keys(): will give the exact same output as for name in favourite_languages:
favourite_languages = {
    'jen' : 'python',
    'sarah' : 'c',
    'edward' : 'ruby',
    'phil' : 'python' # omitting the final comma (,) will work the same as having it in but the code looks more like the english language, which is a upside.
}
friends  = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(f"Hi, {name.title()}!")

    if name in friends:
        language = favourite_languages[name].title()
        print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")
```

Comment: `favourite_languages` is a dictionary, and that syntax is how you access the value of that given key. So if you want phil's favourite language, you would do `favourite_languages['phil']` OR `favourite_languages.get('phil')` so that is why they use the `name` variable there. Not  sure why they don't just loop through `favourite_languages.items()` though

Comment: "Is it like the key which accesses the value of the current key that you are looping through" yes, exactly. With dictionary you get a value by using `my_dict[key_here]` and when you loop through dictionary it's `for key in my_dict` (or like here `for key in my_dict.keys()` for readability). Instead of usual `key`, the variable here is named `name` because in this dict they are people names.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you do *not* understand? "Is it like the key which accesses the value of the current key that you are looping through?" is exactly what happens here. What more information do you need?

Comment: It's fine MisterMiyagi, it was what [name] does, which is the key to the value. So when I loop through it picks up the values from the friends list which are phil and sarah and then gets the value from phil and sarah, which Python and C. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here `name` is a key of `favorite languages`. If you print `favourite_languages.keys()`, it will show you the list of keys `['jen', 'sarah', 'edward', 'phil']`. So, here `if` condition specifies that if name is phil or sarah, then only print the name and the language they love.

Another way of getting the values of key is using `get()`. You can use `get()` which is much more secure than `[]`. `get()` can take optional argument if no any key is present in dictionary. Like `favourite_languages.get(name, 'No name')`

Answer (score 0):

The second line basically gets the language that the name likes. For example, `favourite_languages['sarah'].title()` returns the value of the key called `'sarah'`, which would be "c".

Comment: It will be "C" because you quoted the thing together with .title() which changes case

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your for loop you give a name to the key (The left side of the dictionary). So within the for loop you can refer the keys as name. Does this answer your question?